# Bound on a sum over primes $\sum \frac{\log p}{p}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I would like to prove the following 
$$
\sum_{w \leq p \leq z} \frac{\log p}{p} - \log (z/w) \leq C
$$
where the sum is over the primes $p$ and $C>0$ is some constant. 
(and $w \geq 2$). I have tried using partial summation with prime number theorem, but I haven't been able to get the bound.. Any comments would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you aware of the equality $\sum_{p \leq z} \frac{\log p}{p} = \log z + O(1)$?

Comment: @ParthivBasu How do you prove it? I can see that the bound in question would follow immediately from this

Comment: The proof is a bit involved. You could google Mertens' theorems or Mertens' estimates for the proof.

Comment: I would say it follows from $\log {2n \choose n} = \sum_{p^k}( \lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor-2\lfloor n/p^k \rfloor ) \log p$

Comment: @reuns If it's not too difficult to write down, I would be interested in seeing how it follows from this identity